# how to write html table in .txt file using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I want to export datatable records in .txt file and am using doing this with file handling function but when I am  trying to create table in txt file it will give me the following output:

[image]

by doing this

```
    $fileName = 'filenametxt'.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').".txt";
    $filePath = $upload_path.'/file_folder_txt/';
    $fileNameWithPath = $filePath.$fileName;

    $txtHeaderData .= '<table id="" class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-    table-striped uk-table-condensed" border="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Filed Name</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th>Description of Fields</th>
        </tr>

    ';
    $txtHeaderData .= '</table>';
    $handle = fopen($fileNameWithPath, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $txtHeaderData);
```

but the expected output is:

[image]

can some please help me that how I can achieve this?

Comment: its looks same to me? with headings. u r not using any loop for printing data?

Comment: There is no `<tr><th colspan="4">Header Record</th></tr>` as far as I can see

Comment: @devpro right now am just printing its heading only but it is printing as text instead of table header

Comment: @PriyankaMehra do you want an exact table in a text file, not code? m i right?

Comment: @M.Hemant, yes i need a table format

Comment: @PriyankaMehra with your above code you cannot do that in a text file you can do that in doc file please try, you just need to figure out your class things or need to write table's setting in table tag

Answer (score 0):

The table you see/want is just a default HTML table, styled by the browser. TXT files only hold text no styling, which your file seems to be doing pretty good.

You could write the output as a CSV file, which would allow people to view the file in Excel (basically on big table)

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
$fields = array("location", "field name", "length", "description");
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
```

I haven't had time to test this code, but according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) it should work.

You could also write your own txt table, tho I do not recommend this since some columns will always be larger than others.

```
$csvHeaderData = "----------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
$csvHeaderData .= "| Location | Field name | Length | Description |" . PHP_EOL;
$csvHeaderData .= "---------------------------------------";
```